# How can I easily Ignore [<Fact(Skip="~~")>] annotation?

Tags: f#, xunit

I have many test code lines annotated with `[<Fact(Skip="~~")>]` expression.

However, when I run test with `dotnet test` command, they are not considered as active test cases.

How can I easily convert them into active test cases?

Comment: You remove the '(Skip="~~")' part.

Comment: Or skip the Skip parameter ;)